# Laravel - summing price on my search page

Tags: laravel, search, sum

So a few minutes ago I got a help with my project for summing price with `whereDate` method, and right now all I need is to sum all this price with all methods of payment on my search page, so my search function is for date and when I type date that I want it shows me posts from that date and I need to put price summing in table footer. Let me show you the code.

So this is my `home.blade.php` where I have a regular price summing like this:

```
<tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena') }}&euro;</th>
                    <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>GOTOVINA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'Gotovina')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>VIRMAN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'Virman')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>NK:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'NK')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                </tr>
</tfoot>
```

With `HomeController` index function like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $date = new Carbon(request('date'));

        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(30); //add {{ $posts->links() }} if paginate is enabled
        return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

And now my search page `date range.blade.php` is like this:

```
<tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena') }}&euro;</th>
                            <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                            <th>GOTOVINA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'Gotovina')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                            <th>VIRMAN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'Virman')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                            <th>NK:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->where('placanje', 'NK')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                        </tr>
</tfoot>
```

And my search and index function in `DateRangeController` like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $date = new Carbon(request('date'));

        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(30);
        return view('daterange', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
    }



    public function search(){
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return view('daterange')->with('posts', $user->posts);
    }
```

And my routes in `web.php` like this:

```
Route::get('/daterange', 'DateRangeController@index');
Route::get('/daterange', 'DateRangeController@search');
Route::post('/daterange',function(){
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    $post = auth()->user()->posts()->where('datum_preuz','LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
    if(count($post) > 0)
        return view('daterange')->withDetails($post)->withQuery ( $q );
    else return view ('daterange')->withMessage('Nema rezultata Vaše pretrage. Probajte ponovo!');
});
```

But it shows me error `Undefined variable: date`
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can resume this

```
 $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
 $user = User::find($user_id);
 return view('daterange')->with('posts', $user->posts);
```

In only this

```
 return view('daterange')->with('posts',auth()->user()->posts);
```

About your error:

I think you are doing a wrong use of compact. Compact only receive as parameter an string or array of strings of the vars names. So 'date' is correct, buyt $date is wrong.

Normally you can use compact as this

```
return view('myview', compact('date'));
```

or

```
return view('myview', compact(['date', 'anothervar']);
```

Please try this, and let me know,  :)

Comment: Manuel I'm so sorry for this late answer, I tried what you told me but still the same error ```Undefined variable: date```

Comment: Because the var doen't exist.  I'm not sure if you can use request('date') .... normally i use request()->date or $request->get('date') or Input::get('date');. Maybe you can make a dump dd($date) after create in order to watch if it has something.